# What is the proper content type for JavaScript in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

What content type should I use, if any, in an inline JavaScript block inside HTML?

```
application/x-javascript
text/javascript
```

Or something else?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When serving JavaScript files, is it better to use the application/javascript or application/x-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876561/when-serving-javascript-files-is-it-better-to-use-the-application-javascript-or)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beside that [`application/javascript` is the official MIME type of JavaScript](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4329.txt) , most browsers only accept `text/javascript` or just ignore the `type` attribute value.

Answer (score 7):

According to [the standards](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html) you want to use "text/javascript"

Comment: as Gumbo and Chad mentioned, the current recommendation is actually `application/javascript`; I'd suggest `text/javascript` for backwards compatibility, though; and btw: I think `application/x-javascript` is what Apache sends by default for '.js' files...

Answer (score 2):

text/javascript

Answer (score 1):

After following a few links through the standards I've come to [RFC 4329](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4329.txt) which describes Scripting Media Types. It stats that "text/javascript" is obsolete and says that you should now be using "application/javascript".

Edit: Apparently **no version** of Internet Explorer supports "application/javascript", see: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=338278. So even though "application/javascript" is correct according to the standards, I suppose you need to use text/javascript to compensate for Microsoft's broken browsers (as usual).

Comment: Indeed. And in contrast to what the accepted answer says, IE does not _ignore_ an unrecognised type. It refuses to run scripts with `application/javascript`! So you are forced to use `text/javascript`, or no type at all. (Note: haven't had a change to test all versions of IE; perhaps the very latest does support `application/javascript`. But it's best to play it safe; I'm pretty sure all browsers will keep recognising `text/javascript` for a long time.)