# When serving JavaScript files, is it better to use the application/javascript or application/x-javascript

Tags: javascript, http, content-type

The whole question fits in the title. And to add some context: I'm not asking what is the best according to what the specs are saying, but rather what works the best given the mix of browsers deployed nowadays.

Some data points:

- Google uses `text/javascript` for the JS used on their home page.
- Google uses `text/javascript` on Google Docs.
- Google uses `application/x-javascript` to serve JavaScript files with their [Ajax libraries service](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/).
- Yahoo uses `application/x-javascript` to serve their JS.
- Yahoo uses `application/x-javascript` for the JavaScript served on their home page.

Comment: Funny. You give a third alternative in your examples... And according to Tim, both big players are wrong (with regard to standards), which probably only mean browsers are tolerant (no big news here) and it might no matter.

Comment: possible dupe: [Javascript MIME Type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101394/javascript-mime-type)

Comment: The answers to this question here and elsewhere are ambiguous. A programmer is expected to cross her fingers and hope for the best.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

According to the IETF's [ECMAScript Media Types Updates](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-dispatch-javascript-mjs/) as of 22 February 2021, the [RFC-4329](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4329) is obsolete.

Therefore:

- `text/javascript` is a recommended standard (both by IETF and by MDN)
- `application/x-javascript` was experimental while deciding to move to…
- `application/javascript` is obsolete

Comment: This question from a few months ago says the exact opposite.  Someone is mistaken :)

"Kelly's right, browsers tend to trust the MIME type sent with the response headers over the type attribute of the script tag"

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189850/what-is-the-javascript-mime-type-what-belongs-in-the-type-attribute-of-a-script/189877#189877

Comment: I do not believe this answer is correct. Both Google and Yahoo do not use this method, and I tend to trust them over a green checkmark.

Comment: Oh no! Big, monolithic, slow organisations must be right! The spec must be wrong! Narghh. I'll continue to trust the specification and my own experience over large (slow) companies, even if one of them used to employ me.

Comment: Hmm, someone forgot to tell W3C that text/javascript is obsolete. It seems to be the _default_ in [HTML 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element). ::scratches head::  It also seems (if my cursory reading of this section is correct) that user agents are _supposed_ to go only on the `type` attribute, thus ignoring the `Content-type` would be correct behavior.

Comment: @big_m — That's because lots of browsers don't recognise `application/javascript` so specifying it will cause them to ignore the script. User agents aren't supposed to ignore the Content-Type. The type attribute tells them what to expect. If they don't support it, they shouldn't bother to request it. If the server then says it is something different, they should go on that rather then what the HTML says (at least according to HTTP, you might be looking at a different spec, you didn't provide any links).

Comment: @Quentin, I was referring to the HTML 5 section on the `script` element, that I linked to. My read of that section is different from what you describe; it seems to put a lot of importance on the `type` attribute and makes no mention of checking the `Content-Type`, except for determining the character encoding. I agree that it seems like it would be wise for the user agent to verify that the Content-Type matches what is expected, but I haven't found anything in the HTML spec that requires or even recommends doing that.

Comment: `text/javascript` - according to whom? You mention spec in the comments, but haven't actually cited any in particular.

Comment: Why does your recommendation go against the recommendation in the HTML Standard?

Comment: @MathiasBynens — MIME types aren't the responsibility of the HTML specification.

Answer (score 14):

Here's the 2020 answer to this question.

`text/javascript` is the correct JavaScript MIME type per [the HTML Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#scriptingLanguages:javascript-mime-type), which states:

> Servers should use `text/javascript` for JavaScript resources. Servers should not use other JavaScript MIME types for JavaScript resources, and must not use non-JavaScript MIME types.

And [also](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#dependencies:willful-violation):

> […] the MIME type used to refer to JavaScript in this specification is `text/javascript`, since that is the most commonly used type, despite it being an officially obsoleted type according to RFC 4329.

Work is underway to reflect this reality in an RFC at the IETF level: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-dispatch-javascript-mjs/

Any claim that "`text/javascript` is the obsolete one" is saying so based on RFC 4329, which both the HTML Standard and the abovementioned IETF draft (i.e. an upcoming RFC) are explicitly correcting.

Answer (score 12):

In most situations, the mime type the server sends makes no practical difference.  I would go with [application/javascript](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4329.txt), which is also recommended by an RFC.

Answer (score 8):

It used to be `language="javacript"`. Then it changed to `type="text/javascript"`. Now it is `type="application/javacript"`. Ok this is getting dumb. Some of the older browsers don't recognize the new `application/javascript`, but still recognize the older `text/javascript`. I plan to continue using this, or else I'll waste hours of my time trying to change EVERY instance of `text/javascript` into `application/javascript`.
Now some day the opposite might be true. Some day the newest browsers might reject the old technique in order to be strictly standard's compliant.
But until people viewing my website start complaining that "ever since upgrading my browser, about 50% of your website disappeared", I have no motive to change the code in my website.

Comment: Very prophetic!

Answer (score 7):

If you choose to use application/javascript for js in your pages, IE7 and IE8 will not run your script!  Blame Microsoft all you want, but if you want most people to run your pages use text/javascript.

Comment: When you say that "application/javascript" will not work, do you mean if that is set as the content type on the HTTP response or as the "type" attribute of a script tag?  The original question was on content type on HTTP responses.  Based on other answers it looks like only the value of the "type" attribute on script tags will make a difference either way in IE.

Answer (score 4):

It has been "text/javascript" but this is obsolete (see the [IANA List](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/text/)) and now it should be "application/javascript" (see [another IANA List](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/)).