# ie8 javascript not running or loading

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I have un-installed and re-installed IE8 a few time and javascript will not run. 
I have checked jQuery and numerous sites, and run simple examples like alert("hi"); nothing works. The ie8 developer tools under script debugging says

"Breakpoint cannot be set in this location, the code in the document is not loaded"

This also happens when using the Spoon plugin and IE7 Or IE8.

also any of these scripts work just fine in firefox.

Any ideas or help is much appreciated!

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: Where will it not run?  Not on any site?  Or are you trying to run the scripts locally?

Comment: He wrote, `and numerous sites`.

Answer (score 20):

Go to Internet Options, Security, Custom Level, and enable Active Scripting under Scripting.

Comment: Thanks! 
I had checked the security settings. it didnt work. the javascript dll in IE/windows was messed up and had to be re-registered.

Comment: Wow, just wasted 30 minutes trying to work this one out. Upvotes for everyone!

Answer (score 13):

OS: WinXp service pack2
issue in IE7 and IE8

I had spent alot of time today, uninstalling and reinstalling IE v 7 & 8. I had checked the security settings multiple times. Even disabled my firewall, nothing worked. eventually a friend of mine found  [the clue](http://blog.codepyro.com/2009/11/having-frustrating-day-tring-to-get-ie7.html).

Apparently IE7 & IE8 use the same javascript registered DLL which had become un-registered for whatever reason.

To fix it:
Start > Run...
In the Run box, type in (without quotes) "regsvr32 jscript.dll"
You should receive a popup says that it registration succeeded.

Comment: I received an error, but I had to run command prompt As Administrator. It didn't solve my error, but the registering succeeded xD.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, but the issue for me was the way I defined my block of script.  I used  `type="application/javascript"`.  This is [supposed to be the correct way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876561/when-serving-javascript-files-is-it-better-to-use-the-application-javascript-or) to do it, but IE only wants `text/javascript`.

Answer (score 2):

1. IE -> Tools -> Internet Options -> Advanced -> Disable script debugging (uncheck)
2. ensure  tag ends with > instead of />

Answer (score 2):

None of the above worked for me,

**Reserved keyword**
It was blocked because I tried to invoke my custom export function from my custom object. The 'export' keyword seemed to be reserved in IE.

Chrome works fine comme toujours.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was that IE8, doesn't support `Object.defineProperty`, which lead to all JavaScript not working.

I found out about that problem, when I started debugging JavaScript in IE8 and got the error `Object doesn't support this action`.

Answer (score 1):

[This helped me](https://superuser.com/questions/89392/ie8-refuses-to-run-javascript-from-local-hard-drive), apparently IE doesn't always load script when running from local drive. I had to add a "[Mark of the Web](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628%28VS.85%29.aspx)".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0021)http://www.google.com -->
<html>
```

Answer (score 1):

for my case which was  in IE11 in windows server 2008 R2

at first my site was recognized as **internet zone** which IE Security Level bar was configured **high** and not normal.

but adding my site simply to **Trusted Sites** which have low security via Internet options - Security tab - resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there can be multiple causes for the same symptom.  For me it turned out to be the ActiveX controls/active content was blocked (I'm developing on local and had forgotten that IE likes to make things nice and secure from local).

*Side note: With IE9 (I just upgraded) they moved the 'yellow bar' to the bottom and I was failing to notice it.  MS is missing more than hitting lately on their UX/UI design*

(see for example the ribbon interface visual overload http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/10/03/29/new_office_11_for_mac_sports_dense_ribbons_of_buttons.html)

Answer (score 0):

I tried 
`regsvr32 jscript.dll`, but it didn't work.

Then I tried

```
regsvr32 C:\Windows\System32\jscript.dll
regsvr32 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\jscript.dll
```

And it works!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the JavaScript key **const** lead to an error that stop JavaScript execution. The key word is not support in the IE 10(and early version). See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) for more infomation.