# What is an appropriate content-type header for JavaScript files?

Tags: php, javascript, http

I am delivering a JS response from a PHP file. When setting the `Content-Type` header which value should I use, `application/javascript` or `text/javascript`?

What’s the difference between the two?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876561/when-serving-javascript-files-is-it-better-to-use-the-application-javascript-or

Answer (score 78, accepted):

According to the [IANA Registered MIME media type list](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/), JS has two registered MIME types; the obsolete `application/javascript` and the now official `text/javascript`.

Thus, use `text/javascript`.

**Note:** This answer previously claimed the exact opposite (based on [RFC 4329](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4329.html)), but since [RFC 9239](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9239.html) was published in May 2022 the `text/javascript` media type is preferred over `application/javascript`.

Comment: @some: Wikipedia implies otherwise, but this *is* the correct MIME type. The obsolete one may be used instead, if IE would choke in the correct one.

Comment: @some: I *think*, as per http://annevankesteren.nl/2006/05/javascript-mime-type, that `application/javascript` doesn’t work inside the `type` attribute in script tags in IE 7 and older, but *is* fine for your HTTP `Content-Type` header. I haven’t tested that though.

Comment: I believe this answer is obsolete. See the HTML5 spec which states “Servers should use text/javascript for JavaScript resources. Servers should not use other JavaScript MIME types for JavaScript resources”: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#scriptingLanguages h/t https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21098865/text-javascript-vs-application-javascript#comment110351439_21098951

Answer (score 7):

[According to IANA, on 2022-05-10, `text/javascript` should be used](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml).

Who knows what it'll be in a year!

Answer (score 3):

From [Wikipedia on Internet Media Types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type)

> `application/javascript:` JavaScript; Defined in [RFC 4329](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4329) but not accepted in IE 8 or earlier

There is also the [deprecated `text/javascript`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4329#section-7) (which IE will probably not choke on).

Answer (score 0):

> you should only use `text/javascript`. It's the only MIME type guaranteed to work now and into the future. ~ MDN webdocs

top-voted answer to use `application/javascript` [is obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_Types#legacy_javascript_mime_types)