# How can i insert this javascript code to a php block to run as a block (in Drupal 7)?

Tags: php, javascript, drupal, drupal-blocks

How can i insert this javascript code to a php block? I want to run this javascript in a php block.

```
<script src="http://www.example.com/index.php?section=serve&id=1&output=js</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like this:

`<script src="http://www.example.com/index.php?section=serve&id=1&output=js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>`

It doesn't matter you are working in php or anything else. The fact is whenever the browser sees this tag, it will load the script file from the `"src"` url and executes everything inside the file. So put this tag whenever you wanna load the script in your html document.

Hope it helps
Cheers

Comment: certain browsers might also need you to set the appropriate Content-type header.. hence when serving JavaScript via a PHP script it might help to add a header("Content-type: application/javascript") before sending the actual data body.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987384/what-is-an-approperiate-content-type-header-for-javascript-files

Comment: Thank you @lostsource. Some facts will never change.

Comment: As i said, i want to place it on a block in Drupal 7. I did what you said but it doesn't work. I placed it as plain text, html, php but none of them didn't work. Whats your solution for it please?

Comment: May I ask you first explain what is the response of the "src" attribute, I mean the javascript code you want to be run, then I can say how to do the stuff.

Comment: Happy to hear that body,,, :D