# Node.js res.setHeader('content-type', 'text/javascript'); pushing the response javascript as file download

Tags: node.js

**Scenario**: Consider the following code to give a JavaScript as a response from the Node.JS server.

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
var JS_Script = 'function Test() { alert("test success")}';
res.setHeader('content-type', 'text/javascript');
res.send(JS_Script);
}).listen(8811);
```

**Issue**: It forcing the browser to download the file.

**Question**: How can I make it to render on browser?

**Note**: Working in .net web service with same  `HTTP-header: 'content-type', 'text/javascript'`

So, Its clear following statement does not hold good.
If you want a web browser to render the HTML, you should change this to:

```
Content-Type: text/html
```

**Update**: On inspecting the `content-type` during the download its `application/octet-stream`

But the same when I hit a request with curl, the following is the output:

```
C:\>curl -is http://localhost:8811/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/javascript
Content-Length: 166
Date: Tue, 09 Apr 2013 10:31:32 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

function Test() { alert("test success")}
```

Comment: `res.send()` is an Express-ism and unavailable when you use plain `http`. So I'm thinking your sample code isn't 100% what you're actually using.

Comment: use `application/javascript` as content type

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use `application/javascript` as content type instead of `text/javascript`

`text/javascript` is mentioned obsolete. See reference [docs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4329).

http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application

Also see this question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987384/what-is-an-approperiate-content-type-header-for-javascript-files).

**UPDATE:**

I have tried executing the code you have given and the below didn't work.

```
res.setHeader('content-type', 'text/javascript');
res.send(JS_Script);
```

This is what worked for me.

```
res.setHeader('content-type', 'text/javascript');
res.end(JS_Script);
```

As  robertklep has suggested, please refer to the [node http docs](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.0/api/http.html#response.setHeader), there is no `response.send()` there.

Comment: The `setHeader` isn't even honored, so there's something else going on.

Answer (score 8):

You can directly set the content type like below:

```
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
```

For reference go through the nodejs Docs [link](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_response).