# text/javascript vs application/javascript

Tags: javascript, mime-types

I am curious about the semantics of the MIME types `application/javascript` versus `text/javascript`.

Apart from the obvious - one is intended to be executed, and the other is text.

I see `application/javascript` when looking at headers of an external .js load.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 13 Jan 2014 18:32:58 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5
Content-Type: application/javascript
Content-Length: 856
keep-alive: timeout=5, max=59
Via: 1.1 (jetty)
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

If this `application/javascript` will execute the javascript, why don't we use

```
<script type="application/javascript">
  // some js code.
</script>
```

And vice-versa, why is an external js load not `text/javascript`?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Per [IETF RFC 9239](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc9239.pdf) `text/javascript` is now standard and `application/javascript` is now considered obsolete.

> The media type registrations herein are divided into two major categories: (1) the sole media type
> "text/javascript", which is now in common usage and (2) all of the media types that are obsolete
> (i.e., "application/ecmascript", "application/javascript", "application/x-ecmascript", "application/
> x-javascript", "text/ecmascript", "text/javascript1.0", "text/javascript1.1", "text/javascript1.2", "text/
> javascript1.3", "text/javascript1.4", "text/javascript1.5", "text/jscript", "text/livescript", and "text/xecmascript").

See further notes in [When serving JavaScript files, is it better to use the application/javascript or application/x-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876561/when-serving-javascript-files-is-it-better-to-use-the-application-javascript-or)

Comment: …but the same line says that while it may be obsolete, IE<8 doesn't understand `application/javascript`.

Comment: Sry, I meant IE<=8 whom still many people (not me) want to support. I only meant that you should mention in your answer that there are incompatible legacy engines.

Comment: The [WG spec states that **`text/javascript` should be used.**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#scriptingLanguages) The linked wikipedia article does not contain that information anymore.

Comment: The Wikipedia article linked in this answer no longer contains the "List of common media types" but instead links to the [IANA list of official media types](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml). The entry for [text/javascript](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/text/javascript) can be found in this list and references [RFC 4329](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4329) which indeed declares **text/javascript** to be obsolete.

Comment: According to IETF's [ECMAScript Media Types Updates](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-dispatch-javascript-mjs/), RFC 4329 is obsolete.

Comment: Iana's list of official media types (https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) still lists application/javascript and references RFC 4329. the IETF document you link, @Mike, is only a draft.

Comment: https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/javascript, listed as obsolete in preference to `text/javascript`