# Conflicting of standards about the MIME type for javascripts?

Tags: javascript, browser, mime

[RFC4329](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4329) and [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) says it's `application/javascript`, and `text/javascript` is obsolete. However, HTML standard (by [WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org)) says servers should use `text/javascript` rather than other obsolete types.

Why is there such a difference? What is the correct MIME type we should use for javascripts? Does it mean that web servers should use `text/javascript` for scripts meant to be run by the browsers and use `application/javascript` in other cases (e.g. for a js file to be downloaded)?

Comment: Probably a duplicate

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21098865/text-javascript-vs-application-javascript

Comment: I know there are several similar questions, but none of them provide an explanation and answer about the conflict of standards, and that's why this question is raised.

Answer (score 0):

In most real-world cases there is no difference.

One difference with any `text/*` mimetype vs. `application/*` mimetypes is that implementations *may* automatically convert the character encoding depending on the `Accept-Charset` header without knowing anything else about the text format.

I haven't seen many real world cases where this happens. I believe that most places now use `text/javascript`. I assume that this is the case because `application/javascript` simply hasn't caught on that much.

There's a lot of conjecture here without sources, so take it with a grain of salt. I hope it's helpful.