# What is the CURRENT official/recommended MIME type for Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, mime-types, content-type

I need to know what could be the correct current/future proof Javascript MIME type.

### **References**

[RFC 4329](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4329.txt)- April 2006, seems to say **text/javascript is obsolete** and recommends to **use application/javascript** :

> Use of the "text" top-level type for this kind of content is known to
> be problematic.  This document thus defines **text/javascript** and text/ecmascript but marks them as "**obsolete**".

[HTML Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#dependencies:mime-type) — Updated 2 July 2019 I guess says text/javascript is fine :

> The term "JavaScript" is used to refer to ECMA-262, rather than the official term ECMAScript, since the term JavaScript is more widely known. Similarly, the **MIME type used** to refer to JavaScript in this specification **is text/javascript**, since that is the most commonly used type, **despite it being an officially obsoleted type** according to RFC 4329. [RFC4329]

So at this point text/javascript is correct?

[Internet **Draft** - ECMAScript Media Types Updates to RFC4329](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-dispatch-javascript-mjs-04#page-3), which is said to expire on December 21, 2019, says

> This document updates the existing media types for the ECMAScript
> programming language.  It supersedes the media types registrations in
> [RFC4329] for "application/javascript" and "text/javascript".

> application/javascript - Intended usage:  OBSOLETE

The [first version of the same draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-dispatch-javascript-mjs-00) on October 7, 2017, also says

> text/javascript has been moved **intended usage** from **OBSOLETE to COMMON**.

Also MDN - [Incomplete list of MIME types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types) mention JavaScript MIME type ad `text/javascript`

**Question**

**Part 1**. What would be the correct MIME type at present/after December 21, 2019, if the draft expires/does not expire?

**Part 2**. Should the drafts be followed before they are finalized?

**PS** :

This is **NOT a duplicate** of the following questions. I have gone through most of the main discussions in these questions.

1. [text/javascript vs application/javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21098865/text-javascript-vs-application-javascript) ~ 5+ years old.
2. [When to use the JavaScript MIME type application/javascript instead of text/javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101394/javascript-mime-type) ~ 8+ years old.
3. [When serving JavaScript files, is it better to use the application/javascript or application/x-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876561/when-serving-javascript-files-is-it-better-to-use-the-application-javascript-or) - 10+ years old
4. [What is the javascript MIME type for the type attribute of a script tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189850/what-is-the-javascript-mime-type-for-the-type-attribute-of-a-script-tag) ~ 10+ years old.

Comment: "This is NOT a duplicate of the following questions" — Yes, it is. You want to know what to use in the type attribute, and the spec says to omit it entirely, which is what the duplicate says.

Comment: The question in your title is not the question in your text. The title asks what the correct MIME type is. The text asks what to put in the `script` element. As Quentin says, the correct thing for the `script` element is to leave `type` off entirely when the content is JavaScript.

Comment: The question of what the correct MIME type is remains interesting. I'm fairly sure it's `text/javascript` now, and RFC 4329's vague "known to be problematic" is (13 years later) obsolete. But in pragmatic terms: `text/javascript` and `application/javascript` will be treated the same way by any reasonable consumer of MIME types.

Comment: Re edit: It doesn't matter because it is such a mess now that everything is going to be compatible with everything forever. (That's an opinion. I don't think an answer to that could be anything but an opinion).

Comment: Ok. So you are of the opinion that it might not make much difference even if the draft update proposal to RFC4329 expires (without being replaced by an updated version)?

Comment: Check out [IANA Media Types](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml)

Comment: @phuzi That's because an RFC is by definition more formal and has a more permanent nature than Drafts. Until a new RFC is released, it can never be changed. If a revision becomes necessary, a new RFC is released that makes obsolete or extends the original document. Internet-Drafts should not be regarded as authoritative sources.

Comment: IANA Media Types and any other standards mostly refers to the current RFC, not the draft.