# Why do Firefox warn me when I import PHP-generated javascript with the <script> tag?

Tags: javascript, php, html

In my HTML `<head>` section I import some javascript sources that has been generated by PHP and it works perfectly fine. Here's an example of the generating PHP script:

```
[myscript.php]
<?php
    echo "alert('Hello world');";
?>
```

... and import this with the `<script>` tag like this:

```
<head>
    ...
    <script src="myscript.php">
    ...
<head>
..etc..
```

This is not a problem at all and it works fine. But I have noticed that at least Firefox warns in the Console that the MIME type hasn't be specified for the `<script>` tag. I understand that because the HTML enginge cannot know for sure that the PHP generated contents is javascript... So I added the following:

```
<script src="myscript.php" type="text/javascript">
```

But Firefox still warns me that the MIME typ hasn't been specified. Why is that? Shouldn't my approach get rid of the warning in Firefox? I try to understand why I get the warning, and how to get rid of it.

This is showed in the console (translated): *The script from “http://localhost/myscript.php” was loaded even if it's MIME-type (“text/html”) isn't a valid MIME-type*

Comment: I would try sending a `header('Content-Type: application/javascript');` from the PHP script (First instruction)

Comment: [What is an appropriate content-type header for JavaScript files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987384/what-is-an-appropriate-content-type-header-for-javascript-files)