# How to detect IE6, and show alert?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-6

I'm trying to show an alert when a user using IE6 uses my site.  I'm thinking something like this will work:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
<script language="Javascript">
alert ("The year 2004 just called - they want their browser back!")
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

I'd test this but I don't have a Windows box I can use ATM.  Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: +1: I like the way you think. ;)

Comment: +1 for your edit, MusiGenesis. :)

Comment: If you want to be particularly evil: `<!--[if IE 6]><input type crash><![endif]-->`

Comment: In 2011, we use `type="text/javascript"`, not `language` ;-)

Comment: @Phil Brown Well, IE6 isn't from 2011.  Old-fashioned people get old-fashioned scripts. ;)

Comment: @sudo Good point, I see no fault in that logic

Comment: IE6 was released in 2001, not 2004.

Comment: Yes, but still actual...  in 2004. :)

Comment: @Phil Brown: In 2011, why use either: http://w3.org/tr/html5/scripting-1.html#script

Comment: @Phil: In 2011, we don't use either. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876561/when-serving-javascript-files-is-it-better-to-use-the-application-javascript-or

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes, that works:**

[image]

Of course, you could use [something like this](http://code.google.com/p/sevenup/), which is a bit more friendly.

Comment: Thanks for the link to sevenup, it looks pretty good. Might do that later instead of an alert.

Comment: I've never used it myself, but you're right - "it looks pretty good".

Answer (score 4):

This has already been answered but I really wanted to post something I did for this. 
My personal website, have configured a similar script:

```
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    location.replace("/ie/?next=/");
  </script>
  <![endif]-->
```

So whenever anyone with IE vesion less then 9, the browser redirects to [this page](http://www.rohanjain.in/ie/).

Comment: Not bad! I might do something like that myself. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

This way to detect Internet Explorer version

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
<p>Welcome to any incremental version of Internet Explorer 6!</p>
<![endif]-->


OR 

<!--[if gte IE 6]>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript">
alert("Congratulations! You are running Internet Explorer 6 or greater.");
</SCRIPT>
<P>Thank you for closing the message box.</P>
<![endif]-->
```

More detail you can refer link as here 
**http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512.aspx**

- Thanks
  Abhi.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the code you posted should totally work. Maybe just add a semicolon at the end of the line.

And one more interesting way:

http://www.ie6nomore.com/

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps [this](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd) may be of some use to you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I did state in my answer: *"but I don't have a Windows box I can use ATM"*. So yes, it wouldn't help me. :)

Comment: I didn't give you the downvote, but you got it because it's not useful to the question asker: `I don't have a Windows box`. That extension is `---- WINDOWS ONLY ----`, and even if he did have Windows, it's very unlikely he'd have IE6 installed.

Comment: Sorry about that, I saw this earlier and I thought that this was a cross-platform solution. I should have read more carefully...

Comment: No problem buddy. :)  I didn't down-vote either, not sure who did.

Answer (score -1):

```
#lowCssSupportNotice {
    display: none !important;
    display: block; /* IE6 sees this */
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: -150px 0 0 -150px;
}
```

Comment: `!important` is evil from a usability point of view. Pretty icky to use that when there's more elegant options, like the conditional comment, that will most certainly not influence other browsers.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what usability is. IE conditional comments are proprietary, non-standard code — I'd hardly call them elegant. This will only influence IE6 and other (arguably) irrelevant browsers with incredibly poor CSS support, and is 100% valid, standardized code.