# what is difference between text/javascript and application/javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When serving JavaScript files, is it better to use the application/javascript or application/x-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876561/when-serving-javascript-files-is-it-better-to-use-the-application-javascript-or)

what is difference between text/javascript and application/javascript?

As IE will completely ignore the script tag if you have set type attribute to application/javascript.

But what is the main difference and in which case we need to use the particular.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876561/when-serving-javascript-files-is-it-better-to-use-the-application-javascript-or

Answer (score 63, accepted):

`text/javascript` was introduced when the web was young and people hadn't thought things through.

Then people thought things through, and decided that `text/*` should be reserved for things designed to be human readable (which is why some XML is `text/xml` and other XML is `application/xml`). JavaScript is not human readable, so `text/javascript` was deprecated and `application/javascript` was introduced to replace it.

Years later, some browsers still haven't caught up.

You can configure your server to always serve `application/javascript` in the HTTP headers; browsers that don't support it also pay no attention to the actual content-type.

For the time being, if you are writing HTML 4 or XHTML 1, specify `text/javascript` in the type attribute for the sake of backwards compatibility. If you are writing HTML 5, then omit the type attribute (as it is now optional).

Comment: You make it compatible by doing what I said in the answer.

Comment: It is specific to the server, and it probably is another question, but one for Server Fault rather then Stack Overflow (although setting up MIME/Content types should be fairly easier to figure out from the manual)

Comment: @Thayne — "Human readable" in this context means "You can ignore the tags and read it as English (or French or whatever)". It doesn't mean "It text that you can interpret in your head if you understand the programming language".

Comment: Why is CSS considered "human readable" but not Javascript? As far as I know, I've never seen `application/css`, only `text/css`.

Answer (score 9):

HTML 4.01 (1999) specification suggests using MIME type `text/javascript` (http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.2.2).

However, RFC 4329 (2006) now recommends the use of `application/javascript`.

It seems that historically `text/javascript` was used a lot and since it was the type that browsers most likely supported, this was the type that got suggested also in the HTML specification. Ideally, you would use `application/javascript`.

In practice you may need to use `text/javascript` to provide compatibility with less-conforming browsers.

Comment: That's an example (rather than a recommendation), and one that predates the change in the IANA registered mime type to application/javascript.

Comment: HTML 4.01. See the edit! But yeah agreed, recommends is not the right word (more like suggests or implies). But I agree, this implication is somewhat outdated.