# application/javascript or text/javascript

Tags: javascript, mime-types

I know this has been asked many many times, but [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types#textjavascript) it states that the correct MIME type to serve javascript as is text/javascript, and all other MIME types are depreciated contradicting most answers such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/876805/10421480) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4101763/10421480).

What MIME type should I use when serving javascript content?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [text/javascript vs application/javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21098865/text-javascript-vs-application-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is difference between text/javascript and application/javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122905/what-is-difference-between-text-javascript-and-application-javascript)

Comment: Neither. There is absolutely no need to specify a mime type on a script tag.

Comment: @JaredSmith You are right on the script tag but the mime type is still relevant for setting the corret Content-Type header on the response from the web server.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren very, very true, but since it wasn't tagged node.js and the general tenor of the question I assumed script tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When serving JavaScript files, is it better to use the application/javascript or application/x-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876561/when-serving-javascript-files-is-it-better-to-use-the-application-javascript-or)

Comment: @Jared Smith Ah sorry, i meant what mime type should i use when sending content, i will update to clarify

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The MDN article links to the WHATWG (Web Hypertext Application Technology Working Group, which consists of people from Apple, Google, Mozilla, Microsoft and others) [HTML Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#scriptingLanguages) that was last updated a few days ago. This is the current most up to date HTML specification and it says `text/javascript`.

> Servers should use text/javascript for JavaScript resources. Servers should not use other JavaScript MIME types for JavaScript resources, and must not use non-JavaScript MIME types.

In reality though no browser will break on either `text/javascript` or `application/javascript` so it doesn't really matter. For new projects I would definitely use `text/javascript` but I won't go back and update my old ones.