# Difference between application/x-javascript and text/javascript content types

Tags: javascript, http-headers, content-type

What is the difference between these headers?

```
Content-Type: application/javascript
Content-Type: application/x-javascript
Content-Type: text/javascript
```

Which one is best and why?

Please do not say they are identical - if they were identical there would not have been three of them. I know both work - but I would like to know the difference.

Comment: The difference is also a classic reason why your scripts are not being compressed. Make sure you have an entry in httpCompression for the actual type you are serving and note that IIS Express only compresses application/x-javascript and text/* by default.

Comment: NB: A full list of "javascript mime types" can be found here: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#javascript-mime-type.  i.e. this is the list of values which a browser should allow for a `script` tag's `type` attribute when the `nosniff` directive is specified.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Content-Type-Options

Answer (score 375, accepted):

## The JavaScript MIME Type

When sending JavaScript content, you should use `text/javascript` as per [RFC 9239](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9239).

### Aliases

`application/javascript`, `application/x-javascript`, `text/javascript1.0`, `text/javascript1.1`, `text/javascript1.2`, `text/javascript1.3`, `text/javascript1.4`, `text/javascript1.5`, `text/jscript`, and `text/livescript` are **deprecated** aliases for it. If you are writing a tool which *consumes* JavaScript (e.g. an HTTP client) then you should consider supporting them for backwards compatibility.

### History

The `text/javascript` MIME type was used by convention until [RFC 4329](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4329) attempted to replace it with `application/javascript`.

This was just a change so that the `text/*` and `application/*` MIME type groups had a consistent meaning where possible. (`text/*` MIME types are intended for human readable content, JavaScript is not designed to directly convey meaning to humans).

The industry largely [ignored the specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9239#name-compatibility) so the current specification abandoned the attempt.

### X- prefixes

Some of the MIME types mentioned here use an `x-` prefix. This was used to indicate experimental MIME types that had not been standardised. As per [RFC 6648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9239), this convention is deprecated.

### HTML

While this question is about HTTP, it is worth mentioning the related [`type` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script/type) in HTML.

When loading a traditional script, I recommend you omit the `type` attribute entirely. It has no effect but provides the opportunity to make a typo causing the browser to treat it as pointing to an unrecognised script type and ignore it. If you do provide it, then use `text/javascript` as some deprecated MIME types will not be recognised.

When loading a JavaScript module, use `type="module"` (note that this value is not a MIME type!).

Comment: thanks a lot for the detailed answer . one more issue - you have said that I can omit it entirely (only HTML5 ? ) - but my question (which was later edited by someone) was specifically about JS in PHP -  will it work as PHP/JS combo on all servers/browsers if I will omit it entirely ??

Comment: You can omit the `type` **attribute** on a `<script>` element. You can't omit the `Content-Type` HTTP header … ever (if you don't specify it in PHP then PHP will default to `text/html` which is very wrong).

Answer (score 22):

mime-types starting with `x-` are not standardized. In case of javascript it's kind of outdated. 
Additional the second code snippet

```
<?Header('Content-Type: text/javascript');?>
```

requires `short_open_tags` to be enabled. you should avoid it.

```
<?php Header('Content-Type: text/javascript');?>
```

However, the *completely* correct mime-type for javascript is

```
application/javascript
```

http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/index.html

Comment: Old answer, but don't know if that's good to start with short open tags until that's not a best practice (we strongly recommand you to disable PHP-SOT in fact)

Answer (score 9):

As of May 2022, `text/javascript` is the preferred type once again (see [RFC 9239](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9239.html#name-common-javascript-media-typ))

> The media type registrations herein are divided into two major categories: (1) the sole media type "text/javascript", which is now in common usage and (2) all of the media types that are obsolete

And

> All registrations will point to this document as the reference. The outdated note stating that the "text/javascript" media type has been "OBSOLETED in favor of application/javascript" has been removed. The outdated note stating that the "text/ecmascript" media type has been "OBSOLETED in favor of application/ecmascript" has been removed. IANA has added the note "OBSOLETED in favor of text/javascript" to all registrations except "text/javascript"; that is, this note has been added to the "text/ecmascript", "application/javascript", and "application/ecmascript" registrations.

Answer (score 6):

According to RFC 4329 the correct MIME type for JavaScript should be `application/javascript`. Howerver, older IE versions choke on this since they expect `text/javascript`.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, IE doesn't give a monkey's what the HTTP content type says; only what the HTML `type` attribute says (and in the HTML 5 drafts that attribute may be omitted for JavaScript).

Answer (score 4):

### RFC 9239 Updates to ECMAScript Media Types

As mentioned by itaton, `text/javascript` is the preferred type once again

> This RFC obsoletes RFC 4329 ("Scripting Media Types)", replacing the previous registrations with information and requirements aligned with common usage and implementation experiences.

The reason is due to not following BCP-13, see https://www.rfc-editor.org/info/bcp13

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9239.html#section-6

The reason behind the change:

> Finally, the [HTML] specification uses "text/javascript" as the default media type of ECMAScript when preparing script tags; therefore, "text/javascript" intended usage has been moved from OBSOLETE to COMMON. [rfc9239](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9239.html#section-6)

You can also test out the media types using this website: https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/javascript-mime-type

Answer (score 2):

**Use type="application/javascript"**

In case of HTML5, the type attribute is obsolete, you may remove it. Note: that it defaults to "text/javascript" according to w3.org, so I would suggest to add the "application/javascript" instead of removing it.

> http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-type
>   The type
>   attribute gives the language of the script or format of the data. If
>   the attribute is present, its value must be a valid MIME type. The
>   charset parameter must not be specified. The default, which is used if
>   the attribute is absent, is "text/javascript".

Use "application/javascript", because **"text/javascript" is obsolete**:

> RFC 4329: http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4329.txt
>
> 3. Deployed Scripting Media Types and Compatibility
>
>    Various unregistered media types have been used in an ad-hoc
>      fashion    to label and exchange programs written in ECMAScript and
>      JavaScript.    These include:
>
>    +-----------------------------------------------------+
>        | text/javascript          | text/ecmascript          |
>        | text/javascript1.0       | text/javascript1.1       |
>        | text/javascript1.2       | text/javascript1.3       |
>        | text/javascript1.4       | text/javascript1.5       |
>        | text/jscript             | text/livescript          |
>        | text/x-javascript        | text/x-ecmascript        |
>        | application/x-javascript | application/x-ecmascript |
>        | application/javascript   | application/ecmascript   |
>        +-----------------------------------------------------+
>
> Use of the "text" top-level type for this kind of content is known to    be
>   problematic.  This document thus defines text/javascript and text/
>   ecmascript but marks them as "obsolete".  Use of experimental and
>   unregistered media types, as listed in part above, is discouraged.
>   The media types,
>
> ```
>   * application/javascript
>   * application/ecmascript
> ```
>
> which are also defined in this document, are intended for common
>   use    and should be used instead.
>
> This document defines equivalent processing requirements for the
>   types text/javascript, text/ecmascript, and application/javascript.
>   Use of and support for the media type application/ecmascript is
>   considerably less widespread than for other media types defined in
>   this document.  Using that to its advantage, this document defines
>   stricter processing rules for this type to foster more interoperable
>   processing.

x-javascript is experimental, don't use it.