# Wordpress Blog missing style

Tags: wordpress

I have a blog located at http://air2airheatpumps.co.uk/wordpress (note the lack of a www.)

I have installed wordpress via the 123 reg control panel and as you will see for some reason its missing all the relevant styling, i've checked file permissions, reuploaded the themes etc and for some reason it just won't style. The site_url in the database is also correct.

I've also used chrome's inspector to check for any errors and can't see anything immediately obvious.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Marc

Comment: It seems to return `text/html` as content-type for the css file. This is wrong, it should be `text/css`. If you use apache you can change that via .htaccess with the following line: `AddType text/css .css`.

Comment: *slams head against desk* How on earth did I miss that, so even though chrome is saying its interpreting it right, its actually not, post that as an answer and i'll tick it!

Comment: thank you very much for your response. I have now added a "generic" answer which might help others with similar problems (that's why I have explicitly mentioned the developer tools which, of course, you already use).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are some general guidelines when dealing with problems like that:

- Use the developer tools of your browser (Firebug, IE Developer toolbar or the Chrome Developer tools) to check for the most obvious errors (like wrong filenames). There is no reason to not use them.
- The developer tools most probably highlight files which can't be loaded. Most of the times this is the result of an incorrect URL (like a misspelled filename).
- The `Content-Type` of the files must be correct, otherwise the browser might ignore the contents of the file:

  - `text/css` for CSS files
  - `application/javascript` (text/javascript is apparently [obsolete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9664327/855532))
- Use the developer tools to check what the server sends to the browser.

  - If for example HTML code is sent when loading a .css-file, there could be a rewrite rule which redirects everything to the `index.php`.