# Why do jQuery samples often omit script type?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example [here](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) the code goes like this:

```
<html lang="en">
   <head>
     <!-- whatever -->
     <script>
       $(function() {
         $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
       });
     </script>
   </head>
 <!-- whatever -->
```

Note that `<script>` should have contained `type` attribute (perhaps set to `"text/javascript"`) but it is not present here.

This is not the only example I've seen. Such code makes Visual Studio editor unhappy - it underlines `<script>` and says there should be a `type` attribute. It also makes me curious big time.

Why is `type` often omitted? What happens if I add `type="text/javascript"` - will jQuery break or something?

Comment: did you try adding the type?

Comment: most browsers default to javascript, but you always SHOULD specify the type anyways. JS may not always be the default. It's the buzzword compliant language du-jour, but tomorrow some other language may take over and become the defacto standard.

Comment: @stewbydoo The question isn't how, it's why

Comment: if you're using a modern browser it will know the default is javascript but my co-worker had a simple problem where he forget to put the type and that broke everything. so just include it lol

Comment: @LeeTaylor his last question is will jQuery break if you add it...only one way to find out...so try it

Comment: I remember having a very similar (or related)  doubt  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664282/difference-between-application-x-javascript-and-text-javascript-content-types and got some very good answers

Comment: You missed the first line of the example, `<!doctype html>` very important. That changes to html5 rather than html4, making the type attribute not required.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's probably because [HTML5 does not require a `type` attribute on `<script>` elements](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/scripting-1.html#attr-script-type) (it defaults to `"text/javascript"`).

Comment: "text/javascript" is default type for many-many years. Not for HTML5 only.

Comment: @dfsq, well, the `type` attribute [was required in HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1), so you did have to explicitly specify it.

Comment: That's right. Better to say, that browser will correctly use javascript as scripting language even if it's not specified. But if it's omitted code can be invalid if it's not HTML5 doctype.

Answer (score 5):

In HTML 5 it's now set by default that the script will be of type JavaScript, so there's no need to specify it.
HTML 4.01 does require it though, it seems.

See here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1

And: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#script

Answer (score 4):

It is no longer a requirement in html5.

http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/scripting-1.html

Answer (score 2):

The `type` tag is optional. 
Default programming languages in all browsers has been JavaScript so that is what it defaults to. In XHTML, this attribute is required and unnecessary. In HTML, it is better to leave it out.

The browsers will know it is Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio might be unhappy because it's lazy and needs to parse your code inside `script` tag and intellisense must work as well, so it's better when you provide that `type` directly instead of letting VS guess what language are you using, i.e. `text/vbscript`.

You could write some `html` page with advanced `vb` scripting under Visual Studio.
http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/default.asp.