# What is the exact difference between content-type: text/json and application/json?

Tags: http, header, content-type

What is the exact difference between

1. Content-type: text/json
2. Content-type: application/json

I've been using them randomly and never find any output difference in both http headers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664282/difference-between-application-x-javascript-and-text-javascript-content-types .

Answer (score 67, accepted):

`application/json`: Official MIME type for json

`text/x-json`: Experimental(unofficial) MIME type for json before application/json got officially registered

Comment: Oh please, "MIME type" and "media type" have been used interchangeably for 20 years. unix-like systems still almost all have an /etc/mime.types file, and let me assure you that this file is not used exclusively for mailcap.

Comment: [citation needed]

Answer (score 22):

From the definitions of [Content-Type:](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html)

Two of the seven standard initial predefined Content-Types are:

- **`text`**: textual information. The primary subtype, "plain", indicates plain (unformatted) text. **`No special software is required to get the full meaning of the text`**, aside from support for the indicated character set. Subtypes are to be used for enriched text in forms where application software may enhance the appearance of the text, but such software must not be required in order to get the general idea of the content. Possible subtypes thus include any readable word processor format. A very simple and portable subtype, richtext, is defined in this document.
- **`application`**: some other kind of data, **`typically either uninterpreted binary data`** or information to be processed by a mail-based application. The primary subtype, "octet-stream", is to be used in the case of uninterpreted binary data, in which case the simplest recommended action is to offer to write the information into a file for the user. Two additional subtypes, "ODA" and "PostScript", are defined for transporting ODA and PostScript documents in bodies. Other expected uses for "application" include spreadsheets, data for mail-based scheduling systems, and languages for "active" (computational) email.

*(emphasis mine)*

In other words:

- `text` if it is readable text *(which JSON **is**)*
- `application` if its unreadable binary data *(which JSON is **not**)*

Ideally it would be `text/json`, but [Douglas Crockford registered `application/json`](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/json):

> Applications that use this media type:  JSON has been used to exchange data between applications written in all of these programming languages: ActionScript, C, C#, Clojure, ColdFusion, Common Lisp, E, Erlang, Go, Java, JavaScript, Lua, Objective CAML, Perl, PHP, Python, Rebol, Ruby, Scala, and Scheme.

### So why did he register it under `application` rather than the correct `text`?

Originally it **was** `text/json`. In his [first January 2006 draft:](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-crockford-jsonorg-json-00#section-5)

> **5. IANA Considerations**
>
> The MIME media type for JSON text is **text**/json.

And in his [1st](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-crockford-jsonorg-json-01#section-6), [2nd](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-crockford-jsonorg-json-02#section-6), and [3rd](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-crockford-jsonorg-json-03#section-6) revisions it was still `text/json`.

But by his [4th revision](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-crockford-jsonorg-json-04#section-6) in February 2006, he changed it to `application/json` (with typos):

> **6. IANA Considerations**
>
> The MIME media type for JSON text is **application**/json.
>
> Type name: **`text`**
> Subtype name: `json`

By the time it was accepted as a full [RFC in July 2006](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4627#section-6), any mention of **text** wsa gone:

> **6. IANA Considerations**
>
> The MIME media type for JSON text is application/json.
>
> Type name: `application`
> Subtype name: `json`

Apparently the reason for the change from `text/json` to `application/json` is that the IANA was more likely to hand out an `application/*` rather than `text/*` assignment.

Comment: I agree that `text/json` would have been the more logical (least surprising) choice. I found this answer while researching the reason why `text/json` is *not* the registered MIME type so thanks for providing the historical context.