# Cloudfront distribution with S3 origin download instead of displaying

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, terraform, boto3

I'm creating a cloudfront distribution, cloudfront OAI and S3 bucket using terraform. My bucket has a simple json file.
My bucket has the OAI policy defined properly. When i try to see my json file in my browser (using the distribution url) - instead of showing me the file in my browser - i get it downloaded to my computer. This is not a desired action.

How can i define my file/bucket/distribution, so that when i access the distribution url - i will see the file in my browser?
attached here are my configurations:
Cloudfront distribution:

```
 resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "s3_distribution" {
  origin {
    domain_name = var.bucket_regional_domain_name
    origin_id = var.origin_id
    s3_origin_config {
      origin_access_identity = aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity.default.cloudfront_access_identity_path
    }
  }
  enabled             = true
  default_root_object = "final_catalog.json"

  default_cache_behavior {
    allowed_methods  = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    cached_methods   = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    target_origin_id = var.origin_id

    forwarded_values {
      query_string = false
      cookies {
        forward = "none"
      }
    }

    viewer_protocol_policy = "allow-all"
    min_ttl                = 0
    default_ttl            = 0
    max_ttl                = 0
  }
  viewer_certificate {
    cloudfront_default_certificate = true
  }
  restrictions {
    geo_restriction {
      restriction_type = "none"
    }
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "CloudFront_Distribution"
    Owner = "Gilad_Tayeb"
    Terraform = "True"
  }
}

resource "aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity" "default" {
  comment = "Origin access identity for the distribution"
}
```

s3 bucket:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my_bucket" {
  bucket = var.bucket_name
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_versioning" "my_bucket_versioning" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.my_bucket.id
  versioning_configuration {
    status = "Enabled"
  }
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "allow_oai_access" {
   statement {
     actions   = ["s3:GetObject"]
     resources = ["${aws_s3_bucket.my_bucket.arn}/*"]

     principals {
       type        = "AWS"
       identifiers = [var.cloudfront_oai_arn]
     }
   }
 }

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "allow_cloudfront_oai" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.my_bucket.id
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.allow_oai_access.json
}
```

when uploading my json file to the bucket (using boto3) i'm using my python script:

```
    def upload_filtered_products_to_s3(self):
        with open('final_catalog.json', 'r') as json_file:
            read_data = json.load(json_file)
        bucket_upload = self.client.put_object(
            Bucket=self.bucket_name,
            Body=json.dumps(read_data),
            Key="final_catalog.json",
            ContentType="text/json"
        )
```

if it matters something - i'm wrapping my terraform configuration with terragrunt

Comment: What browser are you using? How big is the json?

Comment: Edge browser, but it acts the same on chrome. The json file have 6 kb of data

Answer (score 0):

The metadata should be `application/json`, not `text/json`. The `application/json` media type is the standard and widely accepted MIME type for JSON content. You can [know about the differences here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22406077/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-content-type-text-json-and-application-jso).

After changing, please invalidate cloudfront then remove browser cache, then check.