# How can I get JSF 2.0 to include JS as 'application/javascript' instead of 'text/javascript'

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, mime-types

In our JSF 2.0 application at work, we include several javascript files via `<h:outputscript>`.

```
<h:outputScript library="javascript" name="DoStuff.js"/>
```

The resulting html references them as 'text/javascript'.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/mycontext/javax.faces.resource/DoStuff.js.jsf?ln=javascript"></script>
```

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876561/when-serving-javascript-files-is-it-better-to-use-the-application-javascript-or), "text/javascript" is obsolete, what's more, htmlunit complains about the type rather verbosely.
Of course, everything works just fine and I could shut off htmlunit's logging, but I'd rather have JSF generate the correct type.

Is there a way to override the type chosen by `<h:outputscript>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is hardcoded in the default renderer of the `<h:outputScript>`. Assuming that you're using Mojarra, it's the `com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.ScriptRenderer`. According to the source, the `type` attribute is been set in the `startElement` method. You could just override it:

```
public class ExtendedScriptRenderer extends ScriptRenderer {

    @Override
    protected void startElement(ResponseWriter writer, UIComponent component) throws IOException {
        writer.startElement("script", component);
        writer.writeAttribute("type", "application/javascript", "type");
    }

}
```

Or if you want to provide the enduser the possibility to specify the `type` attribute itself and default to `application/javascript` when unspecified:

```
public class ExtendedScriptRenderer extends ScriptRenderer {

    @Override
    protected void startElement(ResponseWriter writer, UIComponent component) throws IOException {
        writer.startElement("script", component);
        String type = (String) component.getAttributes().get("type");
        if (type == null) type = "application/javascript";
        writer.writeAttribute("type", type, "type");
    }

}
```

To get it to run, register it as follows in `faces-config.xml`:

```
<render-kit>
    <renderer>
        <component-family>javax.faces.Output</component-family>
        <renderer-type>javax.faces.resource.Script</renderer-type>
        <renderer-class>com.example.ExtendedScriptRenderer</renderer-class>
    </renderer>
</render-kit>
```

---

There's by the way also the nice [`@FacesRenderer`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/render/FacesRenderer.html) annotation which should work as follows

```
@FacesRenderer(componentFamily="javax.faces.Output", rendererType="javax.faces.resource.Script")
public class ExtendedScriptRenderer extends ScriptRenderer {

    // ...
}
```

However, when it's already been definied by a **standard** renderer (the `ScriptRenderer`!), then the custom one will fail to override it by a `@FacesRenderer`. See also [issue 1748](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1748).

Comment: Thank you. As always, your answer looks very thorough. I will give it a shot soon.