# .htaccess gzip is not gzipping certain files according to Yslow

Tags: regex, .htaccess, gzip

I have the following code in my .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN Mod_expires
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 week"
# END Mod_expires

# BEGIN GZIP
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
</ifmodule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)(\?[a-z]*=[\w\.]*$)*">
    Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
# END GZIP
```

It's gzipping everything perfectly, except for the following file:

```
http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/css_theme/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js
```

I tried messing around with the REGEX, but with little success.

How can i also gzip the above mentioned file?

Comment: What is the content type for the JavaScript file? Inspect it in YSlow Net tab.

Answer (score 0):

The *type* for the JavaScript file in question is likely `text/javascript`, which is not in your `AddOutputFilterByType` list.

As mentioned, you can verify this by looking at the response headers.

Learn more - [When serving JavaScript files, is it better to use the application/javascript or application/x-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876561/when-serving-javascript-files-is-it-better-to-use-the-application-javascript-or)

Comment: Content type is `application/x-javascript`. Edit: I have however noticed that some of my other files that use a period in the filename, also don't get gzipped, like: /jquery.flot.min.js. Perhaps this is a REGEX issue?

Comment: I'd still add it for legacy sake. Also, remove your header modification and see if it works. That would prove it's not a gzip problem.

Comment: Its been added. I just removed the header modification and it seems as though nothing has changed. That file is still the only file not being gzipped.