# JavaScript document.createElement not showing

Tags: javascript

I wonder why this code works and shows up in the source and the other code does not?

Code showing up:

```
function test() {
    var scriptElement2 = document.createElement("script");
    scriptElement2.id = 'test';
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement;
    head.appendChild(scriptElement2);
}

test();
```

Code not showing up:

```
function test() {
    var scriptElement2 = document.createElement("script");
    scriptElement2.id = 'test';
    scriptElement2.src = 'http://test.com/ja.js';
    scriptElement2.type = "application/javascript"; 
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement;
    head.appendChild(scriptElement2);
}

test();
```

I only added the two lines :

```
scriptElement2.src = 'http://test.com/ja.js';
scriptElement2.type = "application/javascript";
```

Now the code does not work anymore, the  does not show up in the HTML sourcecode. And yes I tried it with an valid src.

Comment: getting any error on console? Are you using the correct `src` url?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting type to `text/javascript` or leaving it out altogether.

Comment: That worked. But I wonder why ? I always thought it was a good case to set the element type. In previous code I even had to !

Comment: `application/javascript` is the current official MIME type for JS, `text/javascript` is obsolete yet you should use the latter: http://stackoverflow.com/a/876805/358906 - I really want to know why... too.

Comment: Yes I know that but both of them dont work at all, only with completely leaving them out.