# Rails Protect From Forgery with Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, csrf

I am running into a weird CSRF where I am trying to access a javascript file uploaded on my rails server. I have a controller such as:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def show
    some_path = "/some/js/file/on/disk.js"
    send_file(some_path, type: "text/javascript", disposition: :inline)
  end
end
```

However when navigating to `http://localhost:3000/somes/1` I get the error message:

> Security warning: an embedded  tag on another site requested
>   protected JavaScript. If you know what you're doing, go ahead and
>   disable forgery protection on this action to permit cross-origin
>   JavaScript embedding.
>
> Extracted source (around line #225):
>
> ```
>     if marked_for_same_origin_verification? && non_xhr_javascript_response?
>       logger.warn CROSS_ORIGIN_JAVASCRIPT_WARNING if logger
>       raise ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest, CROSS_ORIGIN_JAVASCRIPT_WARNING
>     end
>   end
> ```

Note that I am accessing this page directly which means that there is no layout so I cannot include a CSRF token in my layout.

Is there something that needs to be done differently to correctly access this resource?

EDIT: Per comment request, I have added the Full Trace below.

> actionpack (4.2.6)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:225:in
>   `verify_same_origin_request' activesupport (4.2.6)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:432:in`block in make_lambda'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:239:in `block in
>   halting' activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in`
>   block in call' activesupport (4.2.6)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `each' activesupport (4.2.6)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in`call' activesupport (4.2.6)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in`
>   _run_process_action_callbacks' activesupport (4.2.6)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks' actionpack
>   (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in`process_action'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in
>   `process_action' actionpack (4.2.6)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in`block in
>   process_action' activesupport (4.2.6)
>   lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
>   activesupport (4.2.6)
>   lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in`instrument'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in
>   `instrument' actionpack (4.2.6)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in`process_action'
>   actionpack (4.2.6)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
>   activerecord (4.2.6)
>   lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in`
>   process_action' actionpack (4.2.6)
>   lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process' actionview (4.2.6)
>   lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in`process' actionpack (4.2.6)
>   lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch' actionpack (4.2.6)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in`dispatch'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in
>   action' actionpack (4.2.6)
>   lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in`dispatch' actionpack
>   (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in`block
>   in serve' actionpack (4.2.6)
>   lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each' actionpack (4.2.6)
>   lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in`serve' actionpack (4.2.6)
>   lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:817:in `call' bullet (5.1.1)
>   lib/bullet/rack.rb:12:in`call' warden (1.2.6)
>   lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call' warden (1.2.6)
>   lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in`catch' warden (1.2.6)
>   lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call' rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in`
>   call' rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call' rack
>   (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in`call' actionpack (4.2.6)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in`
>   call' rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
>   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in`call' actionpack
>   (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
>   activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in`call'
>   activerecord (4.2.6)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in
>   `call' activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in`
>   call' actionpack (4.2.6)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in`
>   **run_callbacks**' activesupport (4.2.6)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in`
>   run_callbacks' actionpack (4.2.6)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call' actionpack
>   (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in`call'
>   actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in
>   `call' actionpack (4.2.6)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in`call'
>   web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in
>   call' web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in`catch'
>   web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
>   actionpack (4.2.6)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in`call'
>   railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app' railties
>   (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in`block in call' activesupport
>   (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
>   activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in`
>   tagged' activesupport (4.2.6)
>   lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged' railties (4.2.6)
>   lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in`call' quiet_assets (1.1.0)
>   lib/quiet_assets.rb:27:in `call_with_quiet_assets' request_store
>   (1.3.1) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:9:in`call' actionpack (4.2.6)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call' rack (1.6.4)
>   lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in`call' rack (1.6.4)
>   lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call' activesupport (4.2.6)
>   lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in`
>   call' rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call' actionpack (4.2.6)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:120:in`call' rack (1.6.4)
>   lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call' railties (4.2.6)
>   lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in`call' railties (4.2.6)
>   lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call' rack (1.6.4)
>   lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in`call' puma (3.5.0)
>   lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call' puma (3.5.0)
>   lib/puma/server.rb:569:in`handle_request' puma (3.5.0)
>   lib/puma/server.rb:406:in `process_client' puma (3.5.0)
>   lib/puma/server.rb:271:in`block in run' puma (3.5.0)
>   lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in `block in spawn_thread'

Comment: You are trying to access this resource from where and how? What's the name of the file that source comes from?

Comment: @Leito I am not really sure how the file name is relevant, but it is called sketch.js and stored utilizing Carrierwave

Comment: I meant the file where the error is occurring. The one where line #225 is?

Comment: @Leito Idk then, its some file in rails I am assuming. (The shown code isn't mine, and it didn't give any further information.)

Comment: @Leito I added the full trace in case that helps. Its causing an error somewhere in rails itself.

Comment: Unless the carrierwave js file contains sensitive information, a simpler solution is to store the .js file in the public directory of your rails app and serve it directly from public instead of using a controller. Moving it to the public folder will bypass CSRF checks, and is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 3):

I won't ask why you're using a controller to send a javascript file to the browser even though that doesn't seem like a good idea. I hope these suggestions help.

You could try

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def show
    some_path = "/some/js/file/on/disk.js"

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {
        send_file(some_path, type: "text/javascript", disposition: :inline) 
      }
      format.html {
        "Html request from browser. Try sending a js request to get <Javascript>"
      }
    end
  end
end
```

The other answer is to change the CSRF handling. This is similar to the answer Michal already suggested,

```
    class SomeController < ApplicationController
        protect_from_forgery except: :show 
        ...
    end
```

In my opinion changing CSRF handling approach is much broader in scope. Disabling CSRF for a given method in the controller exposes things that you may not want exposed.

---

Here are some additional suggestions.

It may be old fashioned, but [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) enables one to gain complete control of the HTTP request headers as well as seeing the full HTTP response. By calling `curl -H "Content-Type: application/javascript" http://someurl/here/1` you will be able to see exactly what's happening and why your browser is unable to serve the requested javascript file, or if there is a workaround.

Lastly, if you're trying to serve up static (javascript) files in Rails, there is a lot of extra overhead and potential security risk using a controller to perform that action. Unless there is a very good reason for using the controller, a simpler solution would be to store the files in a sub-directory of the ./public directory on the server, so that anyone and everyone can read the file(s). When you deploy the application to a production environment this could save even more overhead, but that's beyond the scope of your original question.

Good luck!

Comment: btw, the mime type `text/javascript` has been standardized as `application/javascript`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876561/when-serving-javascript-files-is-it-better-to-use-the-application-javascript-or

Answer (score 2):

As error message says, you need to disable forgery protection for this action.

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: :show

  def show
    some_path = "/some/js/file/on/disk.js"
    send_file(some_path, type: "text/javascript", disposition: :inline)
  end
end
```

Comment: This is a current workaround that I am using, however it potentially exposes the application to a csrf attack. Some of the javascript files can potentially be sensitive, so I don't want to leave it open to this.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

1) Make sure to add `<%= csrf_meta_tag %>`in your layout

2) Make sure that you are including the csrf-token hidden field. For instance if you are using a form in the show view. Normally the form builders do it automatically.

3) Set `application/javascript"` in the send_file

```
if request.format.js?
   send_file(assetfilename, type: 'application/javascript')
else
   send_file(assetfilename)
end
```

Comment: The OP is accessing the file directly via `GET localhost:3000/some/1` which invokes `send_file` so there is no layout here.

Comment: As @KyleDecot stated, there is no layout as it is just using sendfile with disposition: :inline in the controller

Answer (score 1):

Checking out the conditions that fire the error:

```
marked_for_same_origin_verification? && non_xhr_javascript_response?
```

I went to the [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/a0e0b67b5afbb02d9ea9e48d71ae80b3efb8c0ac/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb#L222) and found:

```
  # GET requests are checked for cross-origin JavaScript after rendering.
  def mark_for_same_origin_verification!
    @marked_for_same_origin_verification = request.get?
  end

  # If the `verify_authenticity_token` before_action ran, verify that
  # JavaScript responses are only served to same-origin GET requests.
  def marked_for_same_origin_verification?
    @marked_for_same_origin_verification ||= false
  end
```

So that seems to come back true if it's a GET request.

Meanwhile,

```
  def non_xhr_javascript_response?
    content_type =~ %r(\Atext/javascript) && !request.xhr?
  end
```

Which seems to describe your response--a non XHR request yielding a file with text/javascript content.

I suppose that you could avoid this (other than by skipping `verify_authenticity_token`) by forking a branch of rails and changing one of those conditions, or else introducing some layout so the response isn't just javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the check in Rails done in `verify_same_origin_request` that you quote in your question does not actually check the origin. Instead it only checks if (1) it is a GET request, and (2) it is not an XHR request. Your use case satisfies both of these, so the error is raised.

I don't know why the code works in this way. But it does.

Rather than skip the forgery protection completely, you can **just** skip the call to `verify_same_origin_request`.

You can do so by adding this to the top of your controller:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
   skip_after_action :verify_same_origin_request
```